# How to set mongodb to start with authentication automatically

Tags: mongodb

I have mongo setup at an ubuntu host. It currently has no authentication

Mongodb was installed through instructions at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I need to add authentication to it.

These links say as to how to do it
1. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/
2. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

I start mongodb with the command `sudo service mongodb start/restart/stop`

How do we make sure that auth is enabled when we use this method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***UPDATE***: *The following answer was correct for the time question asked (MongoDB 2.x) but it is outdated for current versions of MongoDB. Please consider the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53227658/234775) for the current versions and upvote it instead.*

Use this to ensure mongodb starts with authentication enabled:

```
echo "auth=true" >> /etc/mongod.conf
service mongodb restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that this is present in `/etc/mongod.conf`:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

(The [current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19885291/1837991) seems to be for an old version and might have been correct at the time that it was posted)

Also [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)